# Calculate shear rate with known velocity forcing function and stokes solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software, finite-differences

I have a forcing function of velocity as a function of time (it is a repeating pattern that resembles a sinusoidal function). I want to calculate shear rate as a function of time numerically using finite differences. I differential equation that governs this problem is given as:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nu\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} $$
as per stokes solution found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_problem).
I want to solve this using MatLab, EES, or similar software where my velocity function is entered as an array.

I haven't had to solve a problem like this in a while, and I am forgetting where to start, so any information would be helpful.
[Velocity forcing function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rgq9.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is such a basic problem, that there are certainly enough resources out here to tackle it. A first approach would be to discretize the spatial derivative using [second order accurate central differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) and using [Forward Euler to handle the temporal derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). This gives you an explicit update equation with no need for solving a linear system. Next, you could move on to [Backward Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method) to increase stability of the system which requires you to set up a linear system. In the case you are really interested, you can perform a [von-Neumann stability analysis](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-336-numerical-methods-for-partial-differential-equations-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_336S09_lec14.pdf) to see how velocity $\nu$ is related to timestep $\Delta t$ and grid width $\Delta x$ in terms of stability.